# when to transplant

Tags: trees

My husband has got 6 Maple trees started from the keys in an outside pot. They are now approximately 6 inches tall, should he leave them in the container over the winter or transplant them and bring them indoors until spring

Comment: What part of the world are you in - the answer depends on how cold your winters are

Comment: Bringing them indoors and keeping them in poor light, but warm enough to keep growing, will be bad for them. Whether leaving them outside will be even worse depends on your climate, as Bamboo said. But if they are going to survive outside as mature trees, they should survive as seedlings.